# MongoDB. How to execute stored function in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How can I execute stored function from mongodb. I found solution with `db.eval()`, but it suitable for me.

For example i have document like this:

```
{
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
  mobile: +38000000,
  user: function(user) {
    return user.lastName + ' ' + user.firstName
  },
}
```

Can I somehow execute this function in `node.js`? 
I've tried to get this field and pass it to new Function constructor, it didn't work, also tried to use eval() with it, and also nothing happened.
Maybe there is another way? Would be appreciate for any advise

Comment: Hi what were the error messages when it didn't work?

Comment: It was no error, it just returned undefined. I wrote for example purposes function like this function () { return 0;}. But like i said i get undefined;

Comment: Could you add some of the code you tried in your question to see what you've actually tried so far

Comment: function should not be stored in normal collections it should be stored in `system` collection and can be used in query refer this link http://dirolf.com/2010/04/05/stored-javascript-in-mongodb-and-pymongo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is this:

First store your function as a string. like this:

```
{
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
  mobile: +38000000,
  user: 'function(user) {return user.lastName + " " + user.firstName}' // Save it as string
}
```

Or if you have this function in code somewhere (named function not anonymouse) you can do this:

```
{
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
  mobile: +38000000,
  user: myCoolFunction.toString()  // Note here the toString call
}
```

Then when you fetch this record from mongo db, eval the user property like this:

```
eval("let funcToExec = " + dbRecord.user); // Note that this restores your function back into any variable you want which you can use later in code
// Then execute your function simply like this:
funcToExec({firstName: "Michael", lastName: "Jacksonn"});
```

Let me know if that worked for you!